# Resetting a <select> selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-model, angularjs-select

I'd like to be able to reset the selected `<option>` in the `<select>` to the default one (the `disabled hidden` one).

```
<select ng-model="question1" ng-options="answer as answer.name for answer in $ctrl.question1Answers track by answer.id">
    <option selected disabled hidden>CHOOSE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: would it be the same if you just de-select it from any other options? e.g. `$scope.question1 = null;`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks! It worked! Post a bit more detailed answer and I'll mark it (for future readers).